# Input String was not in a correct format - Error coming only to single user

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to validate the total hours entered should not be greater than the total hours in the current month.

```
 public bool IsValidTotalHours(int month, int year)
    {
        try
        {
            GLLogger.WriteDebugEntry(string.Format("In {0} method.", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name), "LoggingCategory");

            TimeSpan ts;
            int NoOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
            int TotalHoursInCurrentMonth = NoOfDays * 24;

            int iHrsEntranceExitMeeting = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEntranceExitMeetingHrs.Text) ? txtEntranceExitMeetingHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsQAandAMeetings = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQAAndAMeetingsHrs.Text) ? txtQAAndAMeetingsHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsGeneralMeetings = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGeneralMeetingsHrs.Text) ? txtGeneralMeetingsHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsInServices = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInServicesHrs.Text) ? txtInServicesHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsDrugDestruction = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDrugDestructionHrs.Text) ? txtDrugDestructionHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsDriveTime = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDriveTimeHrs.Text) ? txtDriveTimeHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsMSSA = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMSSAHrs.Text) ? txtMSSAHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsMedPass = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMedPassHrs.Text) ? txtMedPassHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsMedRoomInspection = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMedRoomInspectionHrs.Text) ? txtMedRoomInspectionHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsMRR_Time = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMRRTimeHrs.Text) ? txtMRRTimeHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsReportPrepAndPrint = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReportPrepAndPrintHrs.Text) ? txtReportPrepAndPrintHrs.Text : "00");
            int iHrsShortStay_COC_Time = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtShortStayOrCOCHrs.Text) ? txtShortStayOrCOCHrs.Text : "00");

            int iTotalHours = iHrsEntranceExitMeeting + iHrsQAandAMeetings + iHrsGeneralMeetings +
                iHrsInServices + iHrsDrugDestruction + iHrsDriveTime + iHrsMSSA + iHrsMedPass + iHrsMedRoomInspection + iHrsMRR_Time + iHrsReportPrepAndPrint + iHrsShortStay_COC_Time;


            int iMinEntranceExitMeeting = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEntranceExitMeetingMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtEntranceExitMeetingMins.Text) < 10 ? txtEntranceExitMeetingMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtEntranceExitMeetingMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinQAandAMeetings = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQAAndAMeetingsMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtQAAndAMeetingsMins.Text) < 10 ? txtQAAndAMeetingsMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtQAAndAMeetingsMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinGeneralMeetings = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGeneralMeetingsMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtGeneralMeetingsMins.Text) < 10 ? txtGeneralMeetingsMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtGeneralMeetingsMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinInServices = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInServicesMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtInServicesMins.Text) < 10 ? txtInServicesMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtInServicesMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinDrugDestruction = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDrugDestructionMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtDrugDestructionMins.Text) < 10 ? txtDrugDestructionMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtDrugDestructionMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinDriveTime = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDriveTimeMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtDriveTimeMins.Text) < 10 ? txtDriveTimeMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtDriveTimeMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinMSSA = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMSSAMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtMSSAMins.Text) < 10 ? txtMSSAMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtMSSAMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinMedPass = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMedPassMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtMedPassMins.Text) < 10 ? txtMedPassMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtMedPassMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinMedRoomInspection = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMedRoomInspectionMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtMedRoomInspectionMins.Text) < 10 ? txtMedRoomInspectionMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtMedRoomInspectionMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinMRR_Time = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMRRTimeMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtMRRTimeMins.Text) < 10 ? txtMRRTimeMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtMRRTimeMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinReportPrepAndPrint = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReportPrepAndPrintMins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtReportPrepAndPrintMins.Text) < 10 ? txtReportPrepAndPrintMins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtReportPrepAndPrintMins.Text) : "00");
            int iMinShortStay_COC_Time = Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtShortStayOrCOC_Mins.Text) ? (Convert.ToInt32(txtShortStayOrCOC_Mins.Text) < 10 ? txtShortStayOrCOC_Mins.Text.PadLeft(2, '0') : txtShortStayOrCOC_Mins.Text) : "00");

            int iTotalMinutes = iMinEntranceExitMeeting + iMinQAandAMeetings + iMinGeneralMeetings +
               iMinInServices + iMinDrugDestruction + iMinDriveTime + iMinMSSA + iMinMedPass + iMinMedRoomInspection + iMinMRR_Time + iMinReportPrepAndPrint + iMinShortStay_COC_Time;


            ts = new TimeSpan(iTotalHours, iTotalMinutes, 0);
            if (ts.TotalHours > TotalHoursInCurrentMonth || (ts.TotalHours == TotalHoursInCurrentMonth && ts.Minutes > 0))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            GLExceptionPolicy.HandleException(exception, PolicyType.CONTROLLER_EXCEPTION_POLICY, 1,
                                              MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            GLLogger.WriteErrorEntry(exception.Message, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, 1, null,
                                     "LoggingCategory");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

When a particular from his login user enters the hours for MRR time as 11 hours he is the getting the following exception is getting caught

```
 System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.    
 at   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)    
 at   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) 
 at   System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)  
 at   GL.GCRxS.Views.AddUpdateClinicalServices.IsValidTotalHours(Int32 month, Int32 year)
```

If we use a different login in the same machine and add the MRR Time as 11 Hours then we do not get this exception.

Comment: On which line exactly? What is your inputs and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Is it `11 Hours` or only 11 that is entered ?

Comment: It is only 11 that is entered. We are not able to reproduce this error at our end. We picked this error from the log table. But it is reproduced only in the user laptop

Comment: Check date fomat on that laptop and set that format on your pc than you will be able to reproduce it.

Comment: You are getting this error because some string is not being converted to int.You need to change your approach for converting strings to int.

Comment: Its unclear where the issue could be but the solution is to use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you are already converting to 0 if you don't think its valid input anyway

Comment: Do you have a record of the exact input? Is there a space before/after the input? Is the error at the MRR Hours or MMR Minutes section? You should really invest in using [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will alleviate all these converts and potential errors.

Comment: Why are you padding your strings with 0's for the minute section when you are converting them to integers in the end?

Comment: Once you've resolved your problem I strong suggest you post this code on  the code review stack exchange.

Comment: This issue being reproduced only in the user machine. At my end every thing works fine. How can i be able to reproduce this exception at my machine

Comment: I would start by removing as much of the redundant code and refactor the code out a little.  This will help you pinpoint the problem a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

First: Check out the value you are converting. Is it actually a number or does it contain decimal points or something.

Second: Check out the CurrentCulture. Perhaps a cultural setting is different for this user, so the framework is interpreting the input differently. Or... set the current culture to a default value:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("Your country code").
```

Last but not least: Your whole approach with padding is not needed. The user input "9" would parse to the integer 9. So would the padded text "09", which would also parse to 9. So why pad?